# What steps can I take to improve my question?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question [Historical origin of the letters](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/historical-origin-of-the-letters).
The edit history is at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/37254/revisions.
I originally asked "How did the letter symbols develop historically?".
[Historical origin of the letters](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/historical-origin-of-the-letters/37255#37255)
Then someone who answered this question told me that it is to broad, and asked me to narrow it down.
[Historical origin of the letters](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/historical-origin-of-the-letters/37255#37255)
Then I changed my question to "Where did the capital letters and smalll letters come from?". But this version has been marked as needing more focus. So, what steps can I take to improve my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, questions regarding (arbitrary) personal theories are not well-received on linguistics SE, and a few other stackexchange sites. In general, I recommend being explicit with *what* you know, and *how* you know that, and then ask questions based on that. Where relevant, provide citations.

Comment: How do I be explicit with what I know and how I know it?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya Using your scripts question as an example, you could read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Latin_script, cite it, and then ask questions based on that. Also your classifications by straight and curved lines don't fit the paradigm of hand-written latin-based scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, deleting your irrelevant letter classifications is a first step. The second step is realizing that the history of writing is a very broad topic, similar to "how did humans evolve from fish", so you should narrow it, perhaps "how did alphabetic writing evolve (from what)"? Or, how did upper and lower case Latin letters evolve? The third step is to search Ling SE for an existing answer.

Comment: I really need to list the letter classifications somewhere on the web.

Comment: Why? What purpose does it serve?